# Student can't open Word 365 document

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

I am trying to help a student. She has .edu in her email address and is trying to use Word 365.  She has logged on, but when she tries to open a new document, she gets the following error:

> Sorry, we couldn't create your new document
>   You can try again in a few minutes or go to OneDrive for Business now

What is the proper way for a student to open a new document?  When she chooses OneDrive for Business, it does open a new document.  But, since she's a student, not a business, I don't know how successful that will be, or if that is the proper direction.

Comment: This is a document that has been shared by another student or created by said student?

Comment: @Ramhound a new document.  But apparently OneDrive for Business is also for schools?

Comment: Why is the second part of your comment a question?  Office 365 is a product name for both an office subscription service and a cloud service.  OneDrive for Business uses a Sharepoint backend.

Comment: Is the student's Office 365 account a University account? Or something else? Has she tried using her Office account on another computer?

Comment: It is a university account, and she was unable to access the file from another computer.  She copied the text into an email and mailed it to herself, and thus got it to a computer that had standard Word.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a number of different things.  Though she opened it on another system you indicated it Word client - and not the online version so issues may still exists.  I would recommend trying these steps if you encounter it again.

1. Try different browsers to rule out application issues.
2. Try opening it the same way on different system to rule out profile issues or computer issues.
3. Try taking the content of the document and pasting it into a new document to rule out file issues.

If it's number 1 or 2, than additional assistance may be required from IT support. Anything from corrupt profile, to malware could be your issues.

If it's 3 - this happens occasionally where a document appears to work in word desktop client - but has some type of corruption in it and the web version can't handle it.  The web version of word is not as tolerant to file issues as the desktop client is.